# How to properly write in Ruby a validate only on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have now this validate for my User model:

```
validates :email,
            presence: true,
            uniqueness: { :case_sensitive => false }
```

I'd like to add `:on create` for the uniqueness as users are definitely allowed to update their email by putting the same email!

Should I write it this way? I'm afraid the `on:create` also applies to the `presence:true` but it should only apply to the uniqueness validation:

```
validates :email,
             presence: true,
             uniqueness: { :case_sensitive => false }, on: :create
```

Comment: So you are saying that if I edit an user's email, and change it to any other email, that is already exist in users table, it should not throw a validation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to say some logic. Email should be unique and user will be identified by his email. So while update, there is no need to put email field where user can edit the email value. You can make the email field as readonly, so that user can not change it while updating the profile.

And yes, the syntax `on: :create` is the nice solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

yes it will applied on both you can use separate validation for that

```
validates :email,  presence: true

validates :email, uniqueness: { :case_sensitive => false }, on: :create
```